# UTF-8 page to UTF-8 database table showing incorrect

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm hoping for an explanation of why some UTF-8 text is being saved to a database table incorrectly...

I created an HTML form and the page's meta content is set to UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The PHP and template files are all Unicode/UTF-8.

The form field data is submitted to a `utf8_unicode_ci` encoded database table.

If I submit the form with characters such as "éçä" (which I created from Windows' Character Map program set to Unicode character set) they show up incorrectly in the database ("Ã©Ã§Ã¤"). I'm viewing the database via phpMyAdmin (which is also set to UTF-8 character encoding).

However, if I run iconv() on the string to convert to ISO-8859-1 before inserting it into the database, then the character show correctly:

```
$input = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $input);
```

What is going on? Shouldn't the fact that everything is UTF-8/Unicode from beginning to end resulted in it being correct in the DB? What am I doing wrong and why did converting the data to ISO-8859-1 work?

The only other thing done to the data is a FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES:

```
$input = filter_var($input,FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
```

Thank you for your time and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps you haven't mentioned:

- Specify UTF-8 in HTTP `Content-Type` header
- Specify UTF-8 when *connecting* to MySQL, e.g. [specifying `charset` in PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php#refsect1-ref.pdo-mysql.connection-description)

Comment: Ah ha! It was specifying the charset in PDO. Thank you very much, Álvaro.